# Hide/replace menu item when user is logged in/out

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to be able to hide or even replace the 'My account' button when users are logged out and I want to be able to hide or replace the 'Registration' button when users are logged in.

How would I go about doing this? I'm still a amateur at WordPress and I'm still learning, this is what I have so far in my nav-menus.php file.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'My Account' => 'logged-users' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'Registration' => 'not-logged-users' ) );
}
```

I know this isn't correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create both menus, go to **Appearance » Menus**, create the two menus logged-in and logged-out.

After creating the menus, add this code in your theme’s functions.php file or a site-specific plugin:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in'; //This value stands for the actual name you give to the menu when you create it.
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to *hide* them, then I would do this mainly via CSS. WP adds the class `logged-in` to the body element when there is a logged-in user, so you can use that to format elements inside of body differently.

Add classes to your menu items via the admin backend, like for example `hide-when-logged-in` and `hide-when-not-logged-in`.

Then you can use

```
body.logged-in .hide-when-logged-in,
body:not(logged-in) .hide-when-not-logged-in {
  display: none;
}
```

in your stylesheet to hide those elements under the appropriate condition.